# Original vi editor won't leave open mode - unrecognised terminal type

Tags: vi

I downloaded the original Vi editor from here: http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ and it always shows this message (in both xterm and a proper terminal, with `linux` replaced by `xterm` in an xterm):

```
linux: Unknown terminal type
[Using open mode]
```

I tried changing `TERM` to `vt100`, `vt200` etc. but it still comes up with the error. This is annoying because open mode only shows one line at a time, but I want a full screen editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `TERMCAP` variable was not set, I just created a bash script with this command instead, the value was taken from the vi README:

```
#!/bin/bash
env TERMCAP="vt102|$TERM|dec vt102:"' :do=^J:co#80:li#24:cl=50\E[;H\E[2J: :le=^H:bs:cm=5\E[%i%d;%dH:nd=2\E[C:up=2\E[A: :ce=3\E[K:cd=50\E[J:so=2\E[7m:se=2\E[m:us=2\E[4m:ue=2\E[m: :md=2\E[1m:mr=2\E[7m:mb=2\E[5m:me=2\E[m:is=\E[1;24r\E[24;1H: :rs=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h:ks=\E[?1h\E=:ke=\E[?1l\E>: :ku=\EOA:kd=\EOB:kr=\EOC:kl=\EOD:kb=^H: :ho=\E[H:k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:k3=\EOR:k4=\EOS:pt:sr=5\EM:vt#3: :sc=\E7:rc=\E8:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:vs=\E[?7l:ve=\E[?7h: :mi:al=\E[L:dc=\E[P:dl=\E[M:ei=\E[4l:im=\E[4h:' vi $*
```

You can just put the script in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thank you very much that is pretty cool now i get ancient vi working here, but can you explain how this works... And where can i found the real ancient shell used by the ancient unixes or the close to it?

Answer (score 1):

In some unix systems you have to reduce your terminal screen because the terminal emulation doesn't recognize the size. If you have problems even reducing your terminal screen, post to us your operation system and TERM actual value, and if are emulating a remote system or using a local terminal.

And try to use [vim], is more powerful and has some beautiful enhancements.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I am on Debian, and I've tried both on the tty terminals where TERM=linux and the gnome-terminal where TERM=xterm

Answer (score 1):

Have you termcap configuration up-to-date ? This message means that your TERM configuration doesn't work.

To see the valid terminal :

grep '^[a-zA-Z]' /etc/termcap | more

If you have problems with this command or using 'tset' to set and change terminals, try to update installing curses libraries :

apt-get install ncurses-dev

Another tip: modern linux systems use 'xterm-256color'.

Comment: I actually had to run `infocmp | grep '^[a-zA-Z]'`. I know I can use xterm-256color, I can get `xterm|xterm-debian|X11 terminal emulator,` or `xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors,` or `linux|linux console,`.

Comment: I have `ncurses-dev` already installed, and I also get the error in vi `Visual needs addressible cursor or upline capability`

Comment: OK I've actually solved it now, my distro is too modern and doesn't have /etc/termcap

Comment: Thanks for the help, me noticing the lack of a termcap directory led to a solution thanks to your advice